# I believe that an OP jhas just threatened me in a comment

Tags: support

[This question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/12466/who-discovered-pi-and-by-what-method) resulted in a lengthy discussion between OP and myself, culminating in this comment by OP:

> @PieterGeerkens, the whole world in watching you. –  George Chen 54 mins ago

I had already flagged the post as likely more suitable for MathOverflow, so cannot flag it again to have his comment dealt with. As I have a **very unique** name, my address and that of my family is easy to find in Google. This makes me sensitive to what I perceive as potentially being a threat against my person.

Can a moderator please deal with this?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the commenter most likely was grandstanding with the general meaning of "this is Internet, everyone can read this UBER VERY IMPORTANT POST, so you better not act in such a bad way reflecting poorly on you". Granted, that's  just my personal interpretation; I don't mean to denigrade your concerns - just to alleviate your worry.

Comment: @DVK: I accept that possibility - but then "a blatant display of humour" should have accompanied the comment, in accordance with *Poe's Law*, so that I could understand the message: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe's_law

Comment: +1 because I share your concern. In mood, tone or timbre, there is no justification for sounding intimidating.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Pieter. The issue is being dealt with. This is a good opportunity to mention that all of us should conduct ourselves in a civil *and* nice manner. From [the Help section](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/behavior):

> Be nice.
>
> Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated.
>   Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you
>   because we’re all here to learn, together. Be tolerant of others who
>   may not know everything you know, and bring your sense of humor.
>
> Please note that expletives are not allowed. If you use expletives on
>   this site, you may be issued a warning or a suspension.

History is contentious, but everyone on here is trying to find answers to history. We all need to remember that.

Comment: Thank you.  P.S. It really is Pieter and not Peter.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, my apologies about Peter. My mistake.